# How do I make SignalR work inside _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I'm working on an MVC3 project right now and just started using SignalR.

I have followed several demos but I can't seem to get it working when my codes are inside **\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml**. I always get the **"Connection must be started before data can be sent."** error.

Please see my codes below:

**My Class:**

```
 [HubName("notificationsHub")]
 public class NotificationsHub : Hub
 {
    public void updateServer()
    {
        Clients.updateClient("boom");
    }
 }
```

**My script inside _Layout.cshtml:**

```
    $(function(){
       var signalR = $.connection.notificationsHub;

       signalR.updateClient = function (message) {
          alert(message);
       };        

       $("#open").click(function () {
          signalR.updateServer();
       });

       $.connection.hub.start(function () {
          alert("Connected");
       });
    });
```

**Script references:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js")"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
```

My NotificationsHub Class is inside a folder named NotificationsHub which is of the same directory level as my Views.

I tried this on a .html file and it works perfectly (I get the alert callback for $.connection.hub.start).

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Everything looks right to me, I would make sure that all of the script references are being resolved correctly and that there are no connection errors.

Comment: Thanks @Gary.S , I guess I have to look deeper on what's causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's weird, I cannot reproduce the problem. Here's my Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var signalR = $.connection.notificationsHub;

            signalR.updateClient = function (message) {
                alert(message);
            };

            $("#open").click(function () {
                signalR.updateServer();
            });

            $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                alert("Connected");
            });
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    <a href="#" id="open">Open</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Works perfectly fine. Make sure you don't have script reference errors.

Comment: Thanks @Darin Dimitrov . I'll try removing all other script references to find out which one is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Gary.S and @Darwin Dimitrov, you guys were right. 
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script> was causing a reference error. It works now! Thanks!